# What is the least dense rigid congruent sphere packing?

Tags: packing-problem

I was wondering what the least dense rigid uniform packing of congruent spheres was. The lowest density packing of circles is the truncated hexagonal packing.

Comment: There are rigid circle packings with arbitrarily low density: see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RigidCirclePacking.html.

Comment: Both the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing#Jammed_packings_with_a_low_density) and the [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePacking.html) articles on sphere packing cite a [book by Martin Gardner](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0883855178/ref=nosim/weisstein-20) as the reference for the loosest rigid sphere packing. Unfortunately, the articles don't tell us anything about this packing except that is has a density of 0.0555.

Comment: @mjqxxxx: Why does the link imply that one can have arbitrarily low density? I do not think the pictured construction can be iterated, as the adjacent circles are no longer at $120^\circ$ angles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears these very loose packings are not lattice packings. They are periodic, but given a fixed origin, if there are spheres centered at vectors $u,v$ there may not be a sphere centered at $u+v.$ Instead, a condition referred to as rigid or jammed is used.

Gardner, page 88:

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

[image]

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Hilbert and Cohn-Vossen, pages 50-51:

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

[image]

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Comment: The question does not ask for a lattice packing.

Answer (score 2):

The answer seems to depend on what the restrictions are; [Fischer](http://www.oldenbourg-link.com/doi/abs/10.1524/zkri.220.7.657.67105) and [Dorozinski & Fischer](http://www.oldenbourg-link.com/doi/abs/10.1524/zkri.2006.221.5-7.563?journalCode=zkri) present sphere packings of arbitrary low density. See also [Dorozinski's web page](http://www.3doro.de/e-kp.htm#Pkt-2) (in German; [English translation by Google here](http://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=en&sl=de&tl=en&u=http://www.3doro.de/e-kp.htm)).

Answer (score 0):

There are many. They all have arbitrarily low density. Same with circles. Here you can find some: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.1830.pdf

Also note that even in case you restrict your question to uniform-coordination systems, the lowest density packing of circles is not the truncated hexagonal packing. Flakene is less dense: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.01112.pdf